# Почему нужны две переменные и что происходит в данной строчке кода?

Tags: python, email, fetch, mail.ru

Я решаю свою задачку, используя Python 3.11
Работаю с библиотекой imaplib. Подключаюсь к mail.ru

Получаю письмо и извлекаю часть информации о нём
Зная номер письма, я его получаю следующим способом.

```
res, msg = imap.fetch(b'19', '(RFC822)')  #Для метода search по порядковому номеру письма
res, msg = imap.uid('fetch', b'28', '(RFC822)')  #Для метода uid
```

Я хотел разобраться досконально, что происходит в любой из этих строчек.

Для меня было непонятно, **почему используются две переменные для одного или друго выражения**. Так и не понял. Сперва подумал, что это потому, что возвращаемый тип данных у одного или другого выражения - tuple. Но кортежи могут храниться и в одной переменной, потому вопрос все еще остается.

Если убрать одну переменную, то будет ошибка.

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'decode'. Did you mean: 'encode'?
```

Весь код выглядит так:

```
import imaplib
import email
from email.header import decode_header
from configparser import ConfigParser

urlsconf ='config/config.ini'
config =ConfigParser() 
config.read(urlsconf) 

mail_pass = config['login_mail_ru']['mail_pass'] 
username = config['login_mail_ru']['username']
imap_server = "imap.mail.ru"
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_server)
print(imap.login(username, mail_pass))
sent_emails = (imap.select(b"&BB4EQgQ,BEAEMAQyBDsENQQ9BD0ESwQ1-"))
count_mails = int(sent_emails[1][0].decode("utf-8"))
print(count_mails)

res, msg = imap.fetch(f'20'.encode(), '(RFC822)')  
msg = email.message_from_bytes(msg[0][1]) # Извлекаем часть с содержанием
letter_subject = msg["Subject"] # Извлекаем тему сообщения в кодеровке
subject = decode_header(letter_subject)[0][0].decode() # Декодируем в текст
first_word_subject = subject[:subject.find(" ")] # Вырезаем первое слово из содержания
print(first_word_subject)
```

**Расскажите, пожалуйста, почему нужно использовать две переменные и что происходит в данной строчке?**

Comment: Вопрос некорректен. Так бывает нужно делать не только в python, но и в голанге и мало ли где ещё. Ответ простой - функция возвращает две переменных. Обычно, это результат (ошибка) и собственно данные. Так удобнее осуществлять проверку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Метод `fetch()` возвращает кортеж -

> IMAP4.fetch(message_set, message_parts) Fetch (parts of) messages.
> message_parts should be a string of message part names enclosed within
> parentheses, eg: "(UID BODY[TEXT])". **Returned data are tuples of
> message part envelope and data.**

Действительно, этот кортеж можно занести в одну переменную и использовать с индексами:

```
result = imap.fetch(...)
print(result[0])
txt = result[1]
```

Очевидно, что при таком подходе удобство ниже - вместо осмысленных имен переменных - индексы.
Можно сделать по-другому:

```
result = imap.fetch(...)
envelope = result[0]
print(envelope)
txt = result[1]
```

и далее оперировать переменными с осмысленными именами, но получается громоздко.
Удобства добавляет [распаковка](https://pylot.me/article/7-raspakovka-kortezhej-v-python/):

```
res, msg = imap.fetch(...)
# или, нагляднее:
res, msg = (envelop,data)
```

то есть двум переменным за одну операцию присваиваются соответствующие значения из кортежа.
Думаю, что это делается, как отметил в комментарии @strawdog, для удобства, а также для исключения ошибок, связанных с применением индексов (невнимательность, например).